# ANDROID: Is it possible to put more than one location upon loading google maps application

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=14.56643,121.036138 (sample)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to load 2 locations or more in the `Uri.parse()`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Moreover, the specification of `geo:` scheme is under development.

You can find a brief description with samples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

The specification draft is here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00 and it currently doesn't allow multiple locations.